# Add Custom Annotation pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to add the custom annotation pin on the start and end point of the polyline. But I cannot figure how to do that. Here is the image of my map.

[image: Green annotation pin on the current location of user]

I want to add the green annotation pin on the start or end point of the polyline.

Here is my code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (annotation==mapView.userLocation) {

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"currAnno"];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currAnno"];
        }

        annotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"];

        return annotationView;


    }else{

        static NSString *viewId = @"MKAnnotationView";
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView*)
        [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:viewId];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                              initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:viewId];
        }

        annotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"];//set your image here
        return annotationView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two annotations: one annotation with the coordinate of the start of the polyline and one annotation with the coordinate of the end of the polyline. Add both annotations to the map.

Annotation views are centered on the coordinate of the corresponding annotation. If you want the bottom of the green pin in the image to appear at the coordinate of the annotation (rather than the center of the pin image) you'll need to use the `centerOffset` property of the `MKAnnotationView` object to move the image upwards:

```
annotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapPin.png"];
// Move the pin image up 20 points to place the bottom of the pin
// at the annotation coordinate (adjust the value -20 to suit)
annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
```

This example moves the annotation view image up 20 points (a negative y value moves the image up). However, you should use a suitable negative value for your image instead of -20, such as minus half the height of the image or whatever looks right to you.